# VirtualBox on Freenas vm

Tags: virtualbox, esxi

I have a FreeNAS vm running in ESXi 6. I have installed VirtualBox jail on FreeNAS and assigned it a static IP.
I can ping that IP from shell in FreeNAS, but not from any of my other virtual machines. 
They are all on the same subnet.
What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, FreeNAS should not be installed within a VM environment especially for production systems. This is also mentioned repeatedly on FreeNAS support and forums. I hope you are just conducting testing.

Back to your question, have you checked your firewalls / routing on your ESXi VMs, VB VMs, FreeNAS? I haven't tried this particular configuration before but typically its incorrect network settings that prevent pings. Have you tried dynamic IP?